# Segmentation fault at the last line when reading file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got a segmentation fault when reading a file. There is an empty line at the end of the file. I thought when I did fscanf( input, "[^\n]\n", c ), it would take the next line tab from the second last line and the token went to the empty line at the end, which will be '\0', but I got the a segmentation fault.

```
  FILE *input = fopen( filename, "r" );
  if ( input == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Can't open file: %s\n", filename );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  file = ( char ** )malloc( MAX_LINE * sizeof( char * ) );
  int index = 0;
  char *c = ( char * )malloc( MAX_CHAR * sizeof( char ) );
  int length = 0;

  while ( fscanf( input, "%[^\n]\n", c ) != EOF ) {
    if ( c == NULL ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Cannot read line: %d ", index );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    length = ( int ) strlen( c );

    // checking if a line has too many characters
    if ( length > MAX_CHAR ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Line too long: %s:%d\n", filename, ( index + 1 ) );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //checking if the file has too many lines
    if ( index > MAX_LINE ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Too many lines: %s\n", filename );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //printf( "%s\n%d %d\n", c, index, length );

    file[ index ] = ( char * )malloc( MAX_CHAR * sizeof( char ) );
    file[ index ] = c;
    index++;
  }
```

Comment: Try `while ( fscanf( input, "%[^\n]\n", c ) == 1) {`

Comment: `file[ index ] = c;` leaks memory. You copied pointers. You want `memcpy` or `strcpy`

Comment: Hmmm `if ( c == NULL )` test is too late as prior `fscanf( input, "%[^\n]\n", c )` is UB should `c == NULL`.  If `if ( length > MAX_CHAR ) {` is true, then prior `fscanf( input, "%[^\n]\n", c )` is also UB.  I suggest a new approach - use `fgets()`.  Eve, Is that allowed here for you?

Comment: What happend in `fscanf( input, "%[^\n]\n", c )` if your line is larger than your `c` pointeur (MAX_CHAR) ? how do you control that in your program ?

Comment: `if ( index > MAX_LINE ) {` should be `if ( index >= MAX_LINE ) {`